Transform AVMetadataObject coordinates to captured photo
I'm trying to detect a QRCode and take a cropped photo of it using Swift. However I can't transform the coordinates of the detected AVMetadataObject to the correct image space coordinates. This is my prototyping code:
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

class CodeScannerViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput!
    var supportedCodeTypes: [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType] = [.qr]
    var imageView: UIImageView!
    var isCapturing = false
    var codeCorners = [CGPoint]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        
        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else {
            print("Failed to get the camera device")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                captureSession.addInput(input)
            } else {
                print("Failed to add input to capture session")
                return
            }
        } catch {
            print("Failed to create input from video capture device")
            return
        }
        
        photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
        
        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes
        } else {
            print("Failed to add metadata output to capture session")
            return
        }
        
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        
        captureSession.startRunning()
        imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        if captureSession.isRunning {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }
    
    func drawRectangleOn(image: UIImage, corners: [CGPoint]) -> UIImage {
        let imageSize = image.size
        let scale: CGFloat = 0
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        image.draw(at: CGPoint.zero)
        
        previewLayer.draw(in: context)
        
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        path.addLines(between: corners)
        path.addLine(to: corners[0])
        context.addPath(path)
        context.setLineWidth(5)
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        context.drawPath(using: .stroke)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}

extension CodeScannerViewController: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first else {
            return
        }

        guard let photoCodeObject = photoOutput.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObject, connection: photoOutput.connection(with: .video)!) as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else {
            return
        }
        
        if photoCodeObject.stringValue != nil && !isCapturing {
            isCapturing = true
            codeCorners = photoCodeObject.corners
            let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
            photoSettings.photoQualityPrioritization = .speed
            photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
        }
    }
}

extension CodeScannerViewController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
            print("Error while generating image from photo capture data.");
            return
        }
        guard let codeImage = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
            print("Unable to generate UIImage from image data.");
            return
        }
        imageView.image = drawRectangleOn(image: codeImage, corners: codeCorners)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.isCapturing = false
        }
     }
}
        
struct CodeScannerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CodeScannerViewController {
        return CodeScannerViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CodeScannerViewController, context: Context) {
        // Update the view controller if needed.
    }
}

For testing purposes I draw a rectangle around the detected corners in drawRectangleOn(image:). Using photoOutput.transformedMetadataObject doesn't seem to give the correct result, the rectangle isn't anywhere close to the QR-Code on the image.
I also tried to use previewLayer.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObject) and converting the coordinates using this function:
    func convertToImageCoordinates(points: [CGPoint], image: UIImage, layer: CALayer) -> [CGPoint] {
        let scaleFactorX = image.size.width / layer.bounds.size.width
        let scaleFactorY = image.size.height / layer.bounds.size.height
        return points.map { CGPoint(x: $0.x * scaleFactorX, y: $0.y * scaleFactorY) }
    }

Which almost works but I think this fails to take the video gravity into account.
I'm also not happy that the photo output is separate from the detection, which could lead to inconsistencies but I was also unable to get the image data from the previewLayer.
